# Unable to run basic ionic template : Error: Cannot find module 'fast-deep-equal'

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, npm, ionic3

I'm new to ionic and I install the basic blank template as below.

First installed ionic and Cordova using the command

```
npm install -g ionic Cordova.
```

once done created my own first ionic using command

```
ionic start myApp1 blank
```

next cd into the myApp1 directory and tried to run the application using the command .

```
ionic serve
```

but I get below error

```
ionic serve
Error: Cannot find module 'fast-deep-equal'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:513:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:463:25)
at Module.require (module.js:556:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(D:\Proj\myApp1\node_modules\ajv\lib\compile\resolve.js:4:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:612:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:623:10)
at Module.load (module.js:531:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:494:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:486:3)
```

I tried to remove the **node_modules** folder, delete the **package-lock.json**  and install again using the command **npm install** but still same issue.

Ionic version is 3.19.1 and node version is 5.4.2

Please help me to resolve issue.

Answer (score 5):

This error says that your project cant find module 'fast-deep-equal' so you have to install it:

cd into your project and just do:

```
npm install fast-deep-equal
```

if that gives you error, you can delete all content inside node_modules.bin\ and repeat that command.

Hope that helps you to fix that issue, it helped me.